# Why LD_PRELOAD, LD_LIBRARY_PATH and other related things contain "LD", while ld is linker and dynamic loader should be denoted by "dl"?

Tags: linux

I have a little question about naming of things related to dynamic loader in Linux and other Unix based operation systems. All them contains "ld" in name: LD_PRELOAD, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, dynamic loader stores it's configs in /etc/ld.*. I am a little confused by this since ld is linker that's separate thing of dynamic loader. Should it be "DL" instead of "LD" in naming?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "LD" refers to the **loader**, `ld.so`, rather than the linker.